# Docker network/services issue

Tags: docker, flask, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose file with 3 services like the following

```
service:
service1-dev:
(filled with the good config)
network : 
 custom_network
 ipv4_address:167.34.0.5
service2-test:
(filled with the good config)
network : 
 custom_network
 ipv4_address:167.34.0.3
service3-request:
(filled with the good config)
network : 
 custom_network
 ipv4_address:167.34.0.2

networks:
custom_network:
driver: bridge
ipam:
  config:
    - subnet: 167.34.0.0/16
```

Everything work fine and my service1-dev is running on 0.0.0.0:8081
When my dev container is running i can easily acces it with the following in a browser : http://localhost:8081/test
and im receiving my json

The probleme is im running my service3-request that should send some request to my service1-dev but the request are not working.

I don't understand why isn't working both of my container are in the same network 167.34.0.0/16 they both can ping eachother but im trying to do a :
curl http://localhost:8081/test
error 502

OR

curl http://167.34.0.5:8081/test
do nothing

but it doesnt work.

So i don't understand how i can ping all my container but i cannot receive my json when i call my service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well all have to do is to unset my proxy and use the container name in my request `curl http://service1-dev:8081/test`

Everything work perflectly now !

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to some log file to check that 502 error.

Something comes to mind, run `netstat -tanp | grep LISTEN`

This should give you something like that, where :::* means that anyone can connect to that port.

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      2868/cupsd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      3568/master
tcp        0      0 :::42266                    :::*                        LISTEN      2794/rpc.statd
tcp        0      0 :::10080                    :::*                        LISTEN      25226/java
```

As per our discussion - it is possible that flask is made that way for security reasons.
In this way you should install local web server and configure it to server your flask app. Mind you that this is the preferable way to run apps in production!

I would recommend nginx as it is free, very light, super fast and very easy to setup.
https://nginx.org/

And btw read on that topic here: [What does "app.run(host='0.0.0.0') " mean in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31904761/what-does-app-runhost-0-0-0-0-mean-in-flask)

Comment: i did the command and im having this result
`tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8081            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/python`

Comment: Look at the last line in my example - this is now it should look to be seen from outside

Comment: Im not sure how to achieve your result. My service1-dev is an flask app and when i run the flask app i run it like this `app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8081)` with this it should make it public ?

Comment: host='0.0.0.0' is this a param you can change? try '*'

Comment: I try but doesn't work is not a valid param.(i cannot even start my service1-dev) I did read some doc about flask app to have it public i did try what they said in the doc but still doesn't work. It running but i cannot reach it.